# How to make EditText Scrollable only when it is focused inside a scroll view (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, scrollview

I have a scrollable EditText inside a ScrollView, and i want to scroll the ScrollView even when the touch is over the EditText (not focused), and make the EditText scroll only when it is focused
i can write more explanation if needed

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, maybe it will help someone else
CODE SOLUTION:

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    private fun addScrollToEditText() {
        binding.cardYourMessageText.setOnTouchListener(OnTouchListener { v, event ->
            if (binding.cardYourMessageText.hasFocus()) {
                v.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
                when (event.action and MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL -> {
                        v.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false)
                        return@OnTouchListener true
                    }
                }
            }
            false
        })
    }
```